# Should I read the output/error streams if I just want to check if the process starts normally

Tags: java

This piece of code checks whether a process would start normally.

```
protected boolean isInstalled(File executable, List<String> args)
{
    if (!executable.exists())
        return false;

    try
    {
        List<String> cmdLine = new ArrayList<>();
        cmdLine.add(new Path(executable.getAbsolutePath()).toOSString());
        cmdLine.addAll(args);

        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmdLine).start();

        if (process.waitFor(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        {
            return (process.exitValue() == 0);
        }
        else
        {
            process.destroy();
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Do I need to read the streams when I just want to check if the process starts normally? Is it possible for the process to hang in this way?

Comment: If you destroy the process, it won't hang, it will die.

Comment: You always need to consume both outputs. Otherwise the process can block.

Comment: @EJP is absolutely correct. The process you start will potentially write some text to stdout or stderr, this will get written into two queues. If your Java program doesn't read from the queues, they'll get full and then will block your process.

Comment: Or make SURE that your process won't ever write anything to stdout or stderr.